# BotFramework Composer use FactSet to show multiple data

Tags: json, bots, bot-framework-composer

Try to use FactSet to show multiple data inside my AdaptiveCard

this is when i retrieve my data from Database and create my json object

[image]

and here is where i create my Adaptive Cards

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.0",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "speak": "Your flight is confirmed for you and 3 other passengers from San Francisco to Amsterdam on Friday, October 10 8:30 AM",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "FactSet",
      "facts": [
          {
            "$data": "${dialog.productFamily}",
            "title": "${key}",
            "value": "${value}"
          }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the error

```
getProduct.en-us.lg:Unexpected character at Path body[0].facts[0].$data, line 14, position 5 when parsing
```

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive card templating is not implemented in the bot framework SDK yet.
https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6477